# SharedPreferences across multiple activities

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

First, I am sorry if this is a duplicate, I searched and didn't find an answer.

I am trying to keep score across multiple activities. The user starts on the MainActivity, selects a question to answer and is redirected to that activity. The user is awarded a point for a correct answer and is returned to the MainActivity to select a new question.

It is scoring the questions correctly, however it is not saving the score between questions.

**Main Activity**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("userScore", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
    editor.putInt("score", userPoints);
    editor.commit();


};
```

**Q1**(this logic is the same for each question. It runs with a button click)

```
private SharedPreferences settings;
private int userPoints;
private int points;
 public void submitAnswer (View view) {

    if (correctAnswer.isChecked()) {
        userPoints = userPoints + 1;
    } else {
        userPoints = userPoints;
    }

    settings = getSharedPreferences("userScore", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    points = settings.getInt("score", userPoints);

    Toast.makeText(this, "Answer saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Intent intent = new Intent(Q1.this, MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

I am very new to this and I know I am missing something, I just cannot figure out what it is. Any help is very much appreciated.

***EDIT****

This is the button to call the score and it is still only counting 1 out of 6 points.

```
private int userPoints;
TextView pointsAwarded;
ImageButton home;
Button check;
int points;
SharedPreferences settings;    

check.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                settings = getSharedPreferences("userScore", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                points = settings.getInt("score", userPoints);

                pointsAwarded.setText(String.valueOf(points));
            }
        });
```

Comment: In Q1, in think is where you want to update the value, no? You currently do the `put` in Main, and the `get` in the Q1 activity, seems like these should be reversed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is actually a few things wrong with the code. Firstly, you are saving the `score` in the `MainActivity` instead or reading it. And you are reading the `score` in `submitAnswer` instead or editing it.

I am generally pessimistic when dealing with `SharedPreferences` so I check to see if the key has been set with `contains()`.

```
private int points;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("userScore", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    if(settings.contains("score"){
        points = settings.getInt("score", userPoints);
    }
    else{
        Log.e(TAG, "No score yet!");

        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
        editor.putInt("score", 0);
        editor.commit();
    }
}
```

Now in the question Activity you can read the current points from the `SharedPreferences` and update the value and save back to `SharedPreferences`.

```
public void submitAnswer (View view) {
    if (correctAnswer.isChecked()) {
        SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("userScore", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        if(settings.contains("score"){
            int points = settings.getInt("score", 0);
            points++;

            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
            editor.putInt("score", points);
            editor.commit();
            Toast.makeText(this, "Answer saved : points = " + points, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else{
            Log.e(TAG, "No score yet!");
        }
    } 
    else{
            Toast.makeText(this, "Wrong Answer", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    // There is no need to start the MainActivity through a new Intent just call finish();
    finish();
    //... and you return to the Activity that is at the top of the stack.

    //Intent intent = new Intent(Q1.this, MainActivity.class);
    //startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: @Deb :: Please be aware that by using the `finish()` method you will return to the `MainActivity` activity, but you will not trigger the `onCreate()` method. Instead the `onResume()` method will be the reentry point. Please have a look at the Android Activity life cycle!

Comment: @Deb :: Take a look at the changes to the onCreate() method. This should initialize the score the first time around. I have tested this code, for me it works properly.

Comment: @Deb: Please mark this answer as an accepted answer if it solve your problem to close the question ;)

Answer (score 0):

```

```
if (correctAnswer.isChecked()) {
userPoints = userPoints + 1;}
```

```
    after this , u should save userPoints. maybe you forget.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add current user points into saved points and then save it after addition:

```
private SharedPreferences settings;
private int userPoints;
private int points;
public void submitAnswer (View view) {

if (correctAnswer.isChecked()) {
    userPoints = userPoints + 1;
} else {
    userPoints = userPoints;
}

settings = getSharedPreferences("userScore", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
points = settings.getInt("score", userPoints);

userPoints = userPoints + points ; // addition of current userpoints with saved points 

  // Now save this points 
  SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
  editor.putInt("score", userPoints );
  editor.commit();

Toast.makeText(this, "Answer saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
Intent intent = new Intent(Q1.this, MainActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I knew i was forgetting something.